# Finding all $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ mapping arithmetic progressions to arithmetic progressions, with a (not necessarily finite) limit at $+\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, contest-math

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ inconstant so that $\exists \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) $ and for any arithmetical progression $(a_n)$ the sequence $\bigl(f(a_n)\bigr)$ is an arithmetical progression.
> Determine $f$.

Now I think there are quite many functions that satisfy this, but I don't really know how to prove that. For example $f(x)=x$ satisfies the problem, as well as $f(x)=x+n, n \in \mathbb{R}$. Perhaps there are other solutions, but these are the obvious ones.

Any idea?

---

Edit (specification): Maybe the convention is that if $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} x$ it is said that is does not exist. If so, I'm sorry for asking the question the wrong way. In school, they teach us that $\lim = \infty$ is accepted as existent.

Comment: Any linear function would work

Comment: I know this. How can I prove it?

Comment: But $f(x)=x$ has no limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @coffeemath I edited it with a specification, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Is the specification now that the limit is either a finite real or else $\pm \infty$? If so the linear examples are OK and my "answer" becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @coffeemath 
Yes, I am sorry that I did not make it clear in the first place that either a finite real or ±∞ are both accepted. However it becomes clear that only linear functions satisfy the given conditions, now, but still I have a little trouble with proving it

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is not constant, and let $f(x_1)=a,\ f(x_2)=b$ with $x_1<x_2$. Put $d=b-a$ and $k=x_2-x_1$. Consider the arithmetic sequence $y_n=x_1+nk$. Since $f$ preserves arithmetic progressions, $f(y_n)=f(x_1)+nd$, and here $d \ne 0$, so that as $n \to \infty$ we have $|f(y_n)| \to \infty,$ yet $y_n \to \infty,$ so that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ does not exist. Conclusion: only constant functions work.

Since your phrasing of the question begins "Let $f$ ... *inconstant* so that...", the answer as posed is that there are no such functions $f$. However the question would be clearer if you dropped the "inconstant" modifier and just asked about progression preserving functions with a limit at infinity, and then it would be the constant functions as answer, interpreting a constant sequence as an arithmetic progression with common difference $0$.

ADDED: In an edit to the OP, and in some comments, Bujanka has made it clear that the restriction on $f$ is that its limit at $\infty$ may be either a real number or else $\pm \infty$. In this case any linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ has the desired property of preserving arithmetic progressions, and the question remains: are there other such functions?

I had tried for aqn example of a nonlinear $f$ but found it failed to approach $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. If I can fix it I'll put it back in, but for now I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to characterize all such functions:

Let's say $f(0) = a$ and $f(1) = b$. What values can $f(2)$ be? $f(100)$? How about $f(.5)$? $f(\pi)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, then $g(x)$ also satisfies the given conditions, and $g(0)=0$.

Since $x, x+y, x+2y$ are in arithmetic progression, so are $g(x), g(x+y), g(x+2y)$. Thus

$$g(x+2y)+g(x)=2g(x+y)$$

Substituting $x=0$ and using $g(0)=0$ gives $g(2y)=2g(y)$, so

$$g(x+2y)+g(x)=2g(x+y)=g(2x+2y)$$

Let $x+2y=z$. Clearly $z$ can take any real value, so $g(z)+g(x)=g(x+z) \, \forall x, z \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $g(x)$ satisfies the [Cauchy functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

In particular, if $g(x)$ is not linear, then the graph of $g(x)$ defined by $\{(x, f(x))| x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the limit of a sequence of points in the graph of $g(x)$) This contradicts the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty}{g(x)}$ exists.

Therefore $g(x)=xg(1)$ is the only family of solutions, giving $f(x)=x(f(1)-f(0))+f(0) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.